# Find all tokens created by a public key, whose token accounts are not even created

Tags: spl-token, metaplex, spl-token-cli

Suppose I start with the command `spl-token create-token`

And I forget to note down output of above command and now I want to create above token account and mint it. Is there any spl-token command or API where I can list All tokens created by a wallet even if they don't have token accounts?

Answer (score 2):

There's no command to give you all the mints that you own, but you have two options.

- Look at past transactions involving your wallet on an explorer, and find the transaction in which you created the token
- Query all mints for which your wallet is the mint authority using `getProgramAccounts`. Note that most public nodes will probably forbid you from making this call unfortunately, so you'll need to use the first approach